# I think I got the “!want_to_cry.txt” (WannaCry?) virus on my Samba server. Was this inevitable?

Tags: linux, samba, virus, exploit

**Update**: I have checked my note app where I opened the ransome note and the recent open files tab shows me the name of the text file I opened originally. I don't have the contents but the file was called `!want_to_cry.txt`

---

At home I have a Jetson Nano that was running an Samba server with an open port on my homes WiFi. On the 24th, the files there, all had changed file extension to `wantocry`. Luckily, nothing there was of importance but I'm surprised to see it was an exploit mainly used on 2017.

I just realized now, 3 days later. I ended up nuking the Jetson Nano and going around my PCs offline to see if anything else might have gotten affected.

My question is if there's anything specific I should be checking for in regards to my devices if there's a way to know if they are infected.

Also, if there's a known vulnerability in Samba that allows for such a thing. The Jetson Nano had the up to date version of Samba so I was caught of guard. Nothing on the Linux side of the Jetson seemed affected.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151733/discussion-on-question-by-something-new-i-think-i-got-the-want-to-cry-txt-wa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

[WannaCry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack)
is an old virus and well-known to antivirus products.
The infection can be prevented by just updating Windows.

Samba cannot be infected, as this virus infects computers,
specifically Windows. It doesn't infect Linux/Mac machines, so your
computer cannot be infected. You were probably infected by some
Windows computer over the internet, probably because you left
port 445 open.

It's incredible that this virus still exists and is still scanning
the internet, but there might still exist on the internet old
computers that are vulnerable and infected by WannaCry.

Your computer was never in danger, only the files that were
accessible from the internet are lost.

Reference :
[Configure Your Firewalls to Block the “WannaCry” Ransomware Attack](https://www.tufin.com/blog/tech-how-to-configure-your-firewalls-to-block-the-wannacry-ransomware-attack).

Comment: When you say I was infected by some windows computer on the Internet but then say samba can't be infected. I'm confused. Those this imply it was a targeted attack? I had read over how that sense samba utilizes the smb protocol there was a variant called sambacry that was the one infecting samba servers. I'm confused as to if this is a vulnerability on the system or the software

Comment: If your files were accessible over the internet, some infected computer found and encrypted them. This wasn't a targeted attack, the whole internet is continuously being scanned for open ports, and one such scan found your computer. The Samba server itself cannot be infected by this virus, at least on MacOS (SambaCry AFAIK only attacks Linux - [link](https://datagridsurface.com/sambacry-vulnerability-cve-2017-7494/)).

Comment: I wish I knew what version of Samba I had installed but since it's a Jetson I set up no more than 6months ago, I doubt I wasn't running the lastest version of Samba. It'll always bug the back part of my head whether this was anything else or not

Comment: @Somethingnew - A Windows machine on your network encrypted your network share, what version of SMB was enabled, on the server itself is immaterial to the fact.

Comment: @Ramhound: It should have been a computer that wasn't updated for several years.

Comment: I do have several PC in my home but just about all are thrown together in a tower and have been off for months. The only active PCs were off that day I'm pretty sure and they all were absolutely up to date.

Comment: It's why I'm so weirded out. My only other fear is that it was something different mascarating under WannaCry. I don't have any computers that aren't up to date and computers that are actively on is only the Jetson with the only vulnerability being a sba server I set up with open ports on 445 and the other port that window uses for smb.

Comment: It seems that if the Samba server was truly open to the internet, then the infected attack came from outside your network. The server couldn't have been infected, unless you exposed folders that contained software, but it's been wiped out anyway. I think you can feel safe and count this as a good lesson about internet safety.

Comment: @harrymc - For the infection to have happen outside of his network, the share drive, would have had to allow anonymous mounting. I must repeat that, a system within the author's network was vulnerable to WannaCry and became infected with the worm. Which is the reason their network share drive was encrypted.  WannaCry worked in a very specific way, it was a worm, which would reach out to any and all vulnerable Windows machines on the network.  By doing so it would then exploit the SMBv1 protocol and encrypt network drives.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm just checking now searches for the txt file name and post are popping up about samba. This might be something new? https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/794586/wanttocry-ransomware-want-to-cry;-want-to-crytxt-support-topic/

Comment: @Somethingnew - You will have to tell us what you were infected with, when challenged, your story changed slightly. It sounds like WannaCry and it would not be the first time other variants have surfaced with a slightly different name.